# Form-data in spring rest endpoint

Tags: java, spring, rest

How can I create http  POST  endpoint to send data like pictures in spring?

I checked different options and used its but I can not create it.

For example I used:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/web")
public class AuthenticationController {
    @PostMapping(value = "/login", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public void login(@RequestParam(value = "username") String userName,
                      @RequestParam(value = "password") String password) {
    // NOP
   }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: What is actually happening? For testing purposes remove `consumes` from `@PostMapping`

Comment: @Antoniossss Could not resolve parameter [0] in public void *.AuthenticationController.login(java.lang.String,java.lang.String): Required request parameter 'username' for method parameter type String is not present


Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'username' for method parameter type String is not present]

Comment: I think we should avoid using RequestParam to take form data. It will work, but,  when a developer sees a API with RequestParam, it will pass the data using the query parameter instead of using form data. This can cause confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

@PostMapping(value = "/login")
public void login(@RequestParam("document") MultipartFile document) {
`enter code here`
}

Comment: How can I get username and password?

Comment: You can get it like public void login(@RequestParam("document") MultipartFile document,@RequestParam(value = "username") String userName,
                      @RequestParam(value = "password") String password )